# How to properly define this function of function

Tags: functions, function-construction, evaluation, hold

I encountered real problem at first, and here is the toy example

variable `argument` stored some expression that is generated from other parts of the program. I suppose it's content is `{xx, yy, zz}`

```
argument = {xx, yy, zz}
```

and define a function `test`

```
test[argument_,t_] := {argument^2, Range[t]}
```

`test` function has only `t` as variable. Because when I use `test`, I don't need to substitute values into `xx,yy,zz`, I just manipulate expression stored in argument.

Now I want to define another function that has full control of `xx,yy,zz,t`in `test` function in order to get numerical results.

So I tried

```
f[xx_,yy_,xx_, t_] := test[t]
```

This won't work, because `test[t]` is hold. `f[1,1,1,1]` will give

```
{{xx^2, yy^2, zz^2}, {1}}
```

and this won't work either

```
f[xx_,yy_,xx_, t_] := Evaluate@test[t]
```

Though `Evaluate` unhold `argument`, while `Range[t]` can't be evaluated with letter t at the first step. So it will give errors like

> Range::range: Range specification in Range[t] does not have
>   appropriate bounds. >>

So how to do it?

**ps:**

For this simple case, surely I could directly define in this way.

```
f[xx_, yy_, zz_, t_] := test[{xx, yy, zz}, t];
```

But this is not what I want. As I said, the `argument` is dynamically generated by other parts of the program, so we cannot use its explicit form.

Comment: I don't think it's entirely clear what you want to do. Also, did you mean to have separate variables `kx` and `xx` (and the same for `yy` and `zz`)?

Comment: Why can't you define the general function first and the particular case later?  `test[t_]:= f[xx,yy,zz,t]`

Comment: @MichaelWitt Oh, my god. I made a big mistake. I modified my post. I am so sorry

Comment: @rhermans That is because `argument` is dynamically generated by other part of the program in my real case, not like `{xx,yy,zz}` this simple.

Comment: So, when you call `f[xx,yy,zz,t]` you want it to modify the value of `argument`?

Comment: @MichaelWitt That is right

Comment: `f[kx_, ky_, kz_, t_] := Block[{xx = kx, yy = ky, zz = kz}, test[t]]`? But I still don't get why you can't use @rhermans suggestion.

Comment: Ok, if that's all, then try: `f[xx_, yy_, zz_, t_] := {argument = {xx, yy, zz}, Range[t]}`. Does that do what you expect it to?

Comment: @MichaelWitt No, this is not right. As I said to  rhermans, the content of `argument` is generated by other parts of the program, and stored in variable `argument`, so such an assignment `argument = {xx, yy, zz}` means that I already knows the explicit form of `argument`, this is not the case

Comment: @jkuczm Block works! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) inside body of `f` function to temporarily set desired symbols to those passed as arguments of `f`.

```
ClearAll[argument, f, test]
argument = {xx, yy, zz};
test[t_] := {argument^2, Range[t]}
f[kx_, ky_, kz_, t_] := Block[{xx = kx, yy = ky, zz = kz}, test[t]]

f[a, b, c, 4]
(* {{a^2, b^2, c^2}, {1, 2, 3, 4}} *)
```

---

Alternatively you could first define general function `f` and then its specialized version `test` as [suggested by @rhermans](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98506/how-to-properly-define-this-function-of-function#comment267206_98506).

We start with `argument[...]` function instead of `argument` variable:

```
ClearAll[argument, f, test]

Block[{xx, yy, zz},
    argument[xx_, yy_, zz_] := Evaluate[
        Print["Time consuming calculation of argument."];
        {xx, yy, zz}
    ]
]
(* Time consuming calculation of argument. *)
```

Now `argument[...]` gives you precalculated expression with proper values of `xx`, `yy`, `zz` inserted.

```
argument[a, b, c]
(* {a, b, c} *)
```

Now we can define `f` and then `test`:

```
f[xyz:PatternSequence[xx_, yy_, zz_], t_] := {argument[xyz]^2, Range[t]}
test[t_] := f[xx, yy, zz, t]

test[5]
(* {{xx^2, yy^2, zz^2}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}} *)
f[a, b, c, 10]
(* {{a^2, b^2, c^2}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}} *)
```